# Pine Script, Shifting Value from future

Tags: pine-script

If i want to have the close price - SMA(20, offset = 10) - ie current close - SMA20 of 10 bars later, is there anyway to do it?
Of course, the last 10 bars, wont have any value as we dont know the future.
But for historical analysis , i would like to plot such in TradingView.
Is there a way to do so with pint script?

Thanks thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate it from the other way around. In pine we can not reference future values.

```
sma20 = ta.sma(close, 20)

diff = close[10] - sma20

plot(diff, offset = -10)
```